# How to use a Fourier-transform on variable which is multiplied by a constant

Tags: fourier-analysis

I have tried to do this calculation:

```
ℏ := 1.05457168*10^-34

FourierTransform [ψ[x], x, ℏ*p]
```

but the result is:

[image: result]

How can I do it right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `SetDelayed` (i.e., `:=`) in the definition of `ℏ`. Rather use `Set` (i.e, `=`).

```
ℏ = 1.05457168*10^-34
```

Then using an example from the documentation

```
FourierTransform[Exp[-x^2] Sin[x], x, ℏ*p]
```

produces a result with no error.

### Update

Another trick one can use is to perform the transform with a variable (say `ω`) and then perform a substitution after the transform is complete.

```
FourierTransform[A x^3/Exp[x^2], x, ω]

-((I A E^(-(ω^2/4)) ω (-6 + ω^2))/(8 Sqrt[2])) /. ω -> ℏ p
```

which produces

```
(-9.32118*10^-36 I) A E^(-2.7803*10^-69 p^2) p (-6 + 1.11212*10^-68 p^2)
```

Comment: i tried it and something weird happenned: when i used: ψ[x]=A*(E^-x^2) (x^3)  it doesnt work but when ψ[x]=A*Sin[5*(x - 3/2)]*E^-(x - 3/2)^2 everything is just fine.

Comment: In my opinion the equations are easier to follow if you use (for example) `1/Exp[x^2]` rather than `E^-x^2`. Be that as it may, another trick to use is to evaluate it with a variable (say `w`) and then replace `w` after the transformation is complete. See update